# HtmlWindow and custom tag handler make a crash

Tags: wxpython

Using `HtmlWindow` and custom tag handler, I get an assertion error that something is not initialized, and I need help to undestand what I have to initialize:

[image]

After pressing "No", I get a message in console:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'wxPyHtmlWinTagHandler *', no destructor found.
```

The program does work without messages under Linux. The problem appears under Windows 2000, Python 2.7.8, wxPython 3.0.1. The program itself:

```
import wx, wx.html

class VarTagHandle(wx.html.HtmlWinTagHandler):
  def __init__(self):
    wx.html.HtmlWinTagHandler.__init__(self)
  def GetSupportedTags(self):
    return "V"
  def HandleTag(self, tag):
    print "HandleTag V"
    return False

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *ls, **kw):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *ls, **kw)
    h = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
    h.SetPage("<h1>Test</h1><p><V></V>Hello, world!</p>")

app = wx.App()
wx.html.HtmlWinParser_AddTagHandler(VarTagHandle)
wnd = MyFrame(None, title="Just a window", size=(400,400))
wnd.Show(1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Must be a Windows 2000 thing. I just ran it on Windows 7 with wxPython 3.0.2.0 and Python 2.7.9 and it worked fine. I guess you could upgrade to the latest wxPython just to make sure though.